# Why is ItemsControl.ItemsPanelRoot null by default?

Tags: xaml, uwp

[ItemsPanelRoot Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanelRoot)

If ItemsPanel is a template of StackPanel by default (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel)), then shouldn't ItemsPanelRoot return an instance of StackPanel by default?

Comment: What are you doing that this is an issue?

Comment: I already figured out the solution. I was trying to access ItemsPanelRoot too early, and therefore it was null.

Comment: I didn’t ask what it says in the answer below.

Comment: I feel like I have answered your question. And the reason why I need a reference to ItemsPanelRoot is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's null because I haven't yet set ItemsSource. Additionally, even if ItemsSource is set, I need to wait for the `Loaded` event.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution man, you saved a lot of my time.